# How long till Capacitors Discharge Naturally?

Tags: capacitor, safety

I am a super noob at this and never done anything before like this but want to try. Here is the problem I have Samsung SyncMaster 226BW that is known for bad capacitors and I think I am a victim of this and want to try to repair the monitor before shelling out at least $133 bucks for a new monitor.

There are some tutorials on how to open up my monitor and check but I still am gathering information on how to all do this as I never done it before.

Someone suggested that I should discharge the capacitors what makes sense. My plan was to unplug the monitor and then wait a few hours. Open it up what probably be an hour or 2 and then check what capacitors I need and then get them.

So this probably would be 2 to 4 hours when all said and done.

I don't really want to start buying every tool under the sun for this one job but I of course want to do it safely.

I am wondering how many hours should I leave it unplugged till I start working on it?

According to some repair kits you can buy on ebay to fix my monitor problem these are the most common ones that go

- 820uF-25V 105ºC Capacitor
- 680uF-25V 105ºC Capacitor
- 330uF-25V 105ºC Capacitor
- 47uF-50V 105ºC Capacitor

How long should I wait?

Not sure if this makes a difference but the computer monitor will have been on for 8 hours before unplugging.

Comment: You also have a large higher voltage capacitor but as long as you do not come in contact with it or the high voltage side you should be ok.

Comment: We're just supposed to know what a "Samsun SyncMaster 226BW" is?

Answer (score 5):

The highest voltage capacitor on your list is only 50v. This means that (assuming the device is well designed) the highest voltage that capacitor will see is about 25v. That's really nothing to be afraid of. If you've left it overnight, then it will almost certainly be safe to disassemble.

If you really want to be sure though, and if you have a spare resistor, just connect the resistor across each capacitor in turn for a few seconds.

Comment: ha... I was assuming it was CRT... I should have googled the model number... i am deleting my answer.

Comment: No I don't have a resistor or know what it really is. I think I will open up the monitor tonight after the montiors been off for a hour or 2 and just look at what I need. Since I won't be actually taking them out I should be ok??? Realistically it probably won't be till Sunday till I get time to install them and by then it should be discharged. If I see any other ones that I need to replace I will post status updates.

Comment: Should I still take a screw driver and go over it?

Comment: @GradyPlayer - If it was a CRT then I would have not even the thought of trying to repair :)....did not even occur in my mind someone would think I am trying to repair a CRT sorry.

Comment: @chobo2, honestly, if you don't even know what a resistor is, you have no business doing anything inside anything electronic, let alone something that has 120/240 mains power going into it.